# storage account name blob setup: "Validation could not be completed due to an error. If this issue persists, please contact support."

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

"When trying to create blob storage from the free services section, I receive an error message."
"Validation could not be completed due to an error. If this issue persists, please contact support." (Screenshot attached below)

This issue stops me from creating blob storage as the storage account name needs to be validated before the blob storage is created.

I have attempted to input several names ranging from 3 to 24 characters, but I keep encountering an error. Even more frustratingly, when I enter something that clearly doesn't meet the validation requirements, I am informed that it is incorrect. This issue only arises when I input a name that meets the validation criteria.

Does anyone have any insights into whether I am making a mistake or if this is a known issue that Microsoft is addressing?

After attempting to use different browsers and incognito modes, my efforts were in vain.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an user specific error, after searching for a while I came across this blog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1440574/storage-account-name-blob-setup-validation-could-n?orderby=newest#answers

I've used the Cloud Shell for the Azure portal and it works for me. Also, after that, this error won't appear. I don't know the reason for this. Kinda weird.

Comment: problem solved by register the storage service.